# Codeigniter 4 routing not working on live server

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

Please help..i am developing a website.its working fine on local.But when i uploaded it to windows server on godaddy,only default controller working.getting error
*"Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server."*
document root is httpdocs/public.
here is the htaccess  on public.

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

# If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
# change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
# http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
# RewriteBase /

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    

# Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to the front controller, index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
  

# Ensure Authorization header is passed along
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
   # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

and htacces on httpdocs

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex /public/index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|assets|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./public/index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

and here is the route

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Home');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
$routes->match(['get', 'post'], '/Login', 'Home::login');
```

Comment: When you click on a link to another controller function what does your URL look like? Does it have the index.php in it?

Comment: When i type index.php to url it works and when i remove this is the error "Not Found
The requested document was not found on this server."

Comment: Then its a server issue. Since its a windows server I don't know how to solve it on the server side of things. But in codeigniter you can make it use have the index.php in all urls so you can at least have a working site. Remove the .htaccess and in your app config set it to have the index.php in the url.